# why does ImageResizer is rotating automaticlly image photographed vertical and show it horizontal

Tags: imageresizer

Hello i Have uploaded image using ImageResizer 
using this code 
`var instructions = new ImageResizer.Instructions
                    {
                        Width = Convert.ToInt32(Newwidth),
                        Height = Convert.ToInt32(Newheiht), 
                        Format = "jpg",
                        Mode = ImageResizer.FitMode.Crop,

                        Scale = ImageResizer.ScaleMode.Both,
                    };

                    File.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    ImageResizer.ImageJob i = new ImageResizer.ImageJob(File, Filepath, instructions);
                    i.CreateParentDirectory = false; 
                    i.Build();`

i have tried using

```
AutoRotate = true
```

i still got the image rotated to horizontall

i also tried `Rotate=90`
the pic was rotated and lost the proportion here is how it looks like after rotate [image: after pic forced rotated 90]

the resized roteted picture changed it to width=296 height=437  instead of height=296 width=437

the image was taken vertically using samsung galaxy 3 buy when resized it and upload it it show horizonally

here is the original photo taken:
[image: original photo taken]

here is how it shown after uploaded:

[image: Image after using Imageresizer]

Comment: Please post your diagnostics page.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted the diagnostics page, which lists which plugins are installed.

The most likely cause is that you didn't `<add name="AutoRotate" />` or `new AutoRotate().Install(Config.Current)` to install the AutoRotate plugin, and therefore `&autorotate=true` had no effect.

It's also possible that there's a new form of image metadata that we can't detect yet, but that seems less likely.

Answer (score 0):

Try Autorotate property "True"; It worked for me.

```
&autorotate=true
```